# Jquery selector, should I specify type of html tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, performance

I have many html tags with class = 'class1'. They all happen to be/ and always will be the same type of element. For example input elements.

Is there a performance difference between

```
$("input.class1")
```

and

```
$(".class1")
```

Thanks!

NOTE: In this case i need information specifically pertaining to IE8, however a mention of a cross browser solution is important, my clients can only use IE8 so the best answer will have the best answer specifically for IE8.

Comment: should note i my clients in this case will only be able to run ie8

Comment: I would consider editing this information into your question, as the answer wouldn't be the same for anyone writing jQuery code to be consumed by a wider variety of browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a performance difference.  The latter allows the selector engine to use the native `getElementsByClassName` method that exists in most major browsers, and should be slightly faster in browsers that don't support that method **or** `querySelectorAll`.  The former will be faster in browsers that support `querySelectorAll` but not `getElementsByClassName` (which is pretty much just IE 8), but likely still not as fast as the latter for your situation.

For your scenario, use `$(".class1")`.

Comment: So there's a performance difference, depending on which browser you're using, but which is better for overall usage?

Comment: I should have noted in this particular case, i'm developing an internal app and my clients can only use ie

Comment: In the first case, why wouldn't the selector engine use `getElementsByClassName('class1')` then filter the result for tags with `tagName == 'input'`. In browsers that support neither that or `querySelectorAll` I'd imagine the first case would be faster anyways because `getElementsByTagName('input')` would return a much smaller NodeList.

Comment: @MooGoo, that really depends on the selector engine.  Browsers parse selectors from right-to-left and Sizzle imitates this behaviour.  So the `.class1` part of the selector runs first, then a second pass for `input`.

Comment: @kralco: then my answer remains the same - the class name on its own should be faster for you (I updated my answer to clarify the `querySelectorAll` stuff).

Comment: Very interesting. I was thinking that it might be more work for the browser to specify the type of tag, information that I already know. Very good to know! Thanks!

Comment: @Andy E Interesting. I once wrote my own selector engine that parsed the selectors from left-to-right because it seemed logical. But I can see the performance advantages in many cases where the right-most selector is more specific than ones further left.

Comment: @MooGoo - you could keep statistics on which is most common and use that to determine where to start. Like a database does, starts with the most specific criteria.

Comment: @Andy - so clearly this is only meaningful if you have many selectors. In my case I have about 20-30. All of the form `$(".someClass").myFunction("someData");` Do you think it would be quicker to have the html tag have attribute: `something = "somedata"` and do `$("[something]").each($(this).someFunction($(this).attr("something"));` ? Maybe I should ask this as a separate question...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597234/jquery-more-efificent-to-use-multiple-selectors-or-each

Comment: It looks like sizzle.js doesn't make use of getElementsByClassName() if querySelectorAll() is available.

Comment: @DrM: quickly glancing at the code, I think you might be right.  Even then, the single class selector should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure, but I guess there is a difference.

With example #1 there are only the input-elements to walk trough and fetch the elements with the given className, this should be (much?) faster than walk all element-nodes(like in example #2)

Should also depend on the browser-version, I think jQuery will also use things like getElementsByClassName() or querySelectorAll() if available.

Comment: I thought of that too, however does it now how to check every element to see if it is an input and if it has that class, where as without the input helper, does it only have to check the class?

Comment: getElementsByTagName() is the first step(used with 'input' or wildcard '*'-I think so). There shouldn't be significant differences watching at the speed. But the result is different. Of course it takes more time to walk a DOMNodeList with 100 elements than only 10 elements. And that's the 2nd step, walk the list an fetch the elements by their className.

Comment: Well I guess thats what I'm asking. I don't know how it works. If the steps are. 1. Find elements by class name. 2. Iterate that list to determine if they are input elements. Then, if all elements of that class name are input elements it would be quicker not to specify input... no?

Comment: I took a look inside sizzle.js . As browsers that support getElementsByClassName() today  also support querySelectorAll(), there is only 1 Step in those browsers, only querySelectorAll() will be used. In other browsers(e.g. IE<8) the first step is fetching elements by tagname, so I would like to say  the first example is recommendable, the benefits for MSIE should weigh more than the disadvantages in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, including the element name will give you a performance benefit, as (for those browsers that do not support `getElementsByClassName` natively or well) this allows the browser to first pare down the document using the standard method `getElementsByTagName`, and then only search among those for the class.