# Jquery - more efficient to use multiple selectors, or each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, performance

I have something like this

```
<input class = "Class1"/>
<input class = "Class2"/>
<input class = "Class3"/>
<input class = "Class4"/>
...
..
.

$(".Class1").someFunction("data1");
$(".Class2").someFunction("data2");
$(".Class3").someFunction("data3");
$(".Class4").someFunction("data4");
...
..
.
```

is it more efficient to do that or something like this:

```
<input something="data1"/>
<input something="data2"/>
<input something="data3"/>
<input something="data4"/>
...
..
.
$("[something]").each($(this).someFunction($(this).attr("something")));
```

ideas?

Comment: noting that I likely will have at least 20-30 of these inputs I need to call this function on?

Comment: OK. I i guess i was not clear. I need to pass a **different** string to the someFunction called on each input.

Answer (score 1):

As far as fastest selectors go it would be better to do:

```
<div id="container">
    <input data-something="1" />
    <input data-something="2" />
    <input data-something="3" />
    <input data-something="4" />
</div>
```

Then you can do:

```
$('#container input').each(function(){});
```

Comment: How do I accommodate passing in different values to each instance of the function?

Comment: I updated. Use the html5 `data-` attribute http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/.

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of how you select them, you'll need to do an `each()` anyway if your code example is anything like you're real code.This is because you're passing unique data to each function call.

But you should add a `tagName` to the selector at the very least.

```
$("input[something]").each(function() {
    $(this).someFunction($(this).attr("something"));
});
```

Without the `tagName`, jQuery will need to look at *every* element on the page, instead of just `input` elements.

Comment: well if i give each input element a different class name, and select by class name then I can hard code into the java script the value sent to each input. I would not have to use each, but I would have to use a separate selector for each input element.

Comment: @kralco626: It all depends on the ultimate requirements of your application. Ultimately, I'd rather do one DOM selection than several. I wouldn't however use the `class` attribute as a data storage mechanism, if that's what is intended.

Comment: if `someFunction` is a jQuery plugin, or does the each you would not need it.

Comment: @Josiah: Yes, but I can only go by the example, where unique data is passed to `someFunction()` for each element. So I'm assuming that's a requirement, whether in via `.each()` or via hardcoded values.

Comment: And `.attr("something")` should use a `data-something` attribute name so it conforms with html5

Answer (score 0):

`^=` operator matches starts with too:

```
$("input[class^=Class]").each($(this).someFunction($(this).attr("something")));
```